# Get access to existing thread python

Tags: python, multithreading

Pretend one have a script with creating some testing Thread: `test1.py`

```
import threading
import time


class Test(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, name, alist):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.alist = alist
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        print "Starting thread " + self.name
        self.append_to_alist(self.alist)
        print "Exiting thread" + self.name

    def append_to_alist(self, alist):
        for x in range(5):
            self.alist.append(alist[-1]+1)
            time.sleep(10)


def main():
    alist = [1]
    # Create new thread
    thread = Test("Test thread", alist)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    print alist
main()
```

Now I run it `python test1.py` and then I want to run another script `test2.py` in order to modify existing `Test` thread which is working, something like this, `test2.py`:

```
import threading
thread = somehow_get_access_to_Test_thread()
thread.alist.append('test')
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way for the threads to interact directly. Not only are they different threads, but they also run in separate Python processes.

In this case I believe the simplest solution is to have the list thread listen on a TCP port, and the other thread write to that port.

See for example [this library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication).